# Error while starting peers and orderer with the certificates generated using Root and Intermediate CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca, raft

I am trying to implement Root CA and intermediate CAs for my network setup. I have already created Root CA and intermediate CA and have already registered and enrolled all the members of the organisation i.e. orderer, peer, admin, users.

Everything is working fine as I have seen the logs of CAs and they are working properly but when I tried to start docker container of peers and orderers they are not getting up, and by looking at the logs of the orderer and peer I am getting these logs:

```
certificate has expired or is not yet valid yet.
```

Can anyone help me with this as I have tried few times but everytime I am getting this error only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have got the solution here:

https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABC-832

The starting validity period i.e. Not Before of peers is approximately 5 minutes earlier than that of intermediate CA. This is because Fabric CA, by default, backdates the signing of certificates by 5 minutes. So now I have set backdate to 1 second in fabric-ca-config.yaml file:

```
signing:
    default:
      usage:
        - digital signature
      expiry: 8760h
      backdate: 1s
    profiles:
      ca:
         backdate: 1s
         usage:
           - cert sign
           - crl sign
         expiry: 43800h
         caconstraint:
           isca: true
           maxpathlen: 0
      tls:
         backdate: 1s
         usage:
            - signing
            - key encipherment
            - server auth
            - client auth
            - key agreement
         expiry: 8760h
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems more like it is a problem with generating of certificates and not with expiring. So they are either haven't been generated yet or where put in a wrong place.

Try to completely restart the docker at first.
Then, add some buffer time after key generation. You can add `sleep 300` after cryptogen and configtxgen have been called but before the actual docker containers get spun up.

If it doesn't help, try to trace where the certificates are and where are you try to take them from.

Comment: Thanks for the response but that's not the case here. As, I have not generated my certificates using cryptogen tool.